# Is F a vector space over F?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know $F^n$ is a vector space over F (where F is a field)

This statement is true even when n is 1 right?

My professor said otherwise and that got me to ask the question here, please do excuse the silliness of the question.

Comment: Of course.  It's 1-dimensional.

Comment: Yes, $n = 1$ is allowed (also $n = 0$ is allowed, which by definition means a vector space over $F$ consisting solely of the zero vector; this is unique upto isomorphism).

Comment: Of course all of us are a bit sloppy here, technically you should define what you mean by $F^n$ (i.e. what exactly is that set and what addition and scalar multiplication we are looking at). However, this notation is pretty standard and what it denotes is a vector space for all natural $n$, including $n=1$ of course.

Comment: @WilliamM. I had actually never thought of the $n = 0$ case and now I'm curious, how does one actually define the $zero_{th}$ power of a set(or field)?

Comment: @Metric you're not taking "powers" of a field:  it's just notation.  And $F^0=\{\mathbf{0}\}$, the $0$-dim vector space over $F$.

Comment: I understand that one isn't actually taking powers, rather it's a notation to denote n tuples by n fold Cartesian products, even then isn't the 0-tuple typically defined to be the null set $ \varnothing $? I know I am probably being unnecessarily pedantic, and it's probably just better to define $ F^0 $ to be the set $ \{0\} $ and be done with ot

Comment: @Metric Yes, you definitley want to be done with it, because you want the product isomorphism $F^m \times F^n \cong F^{m+n}$ to hold, and this requires $F^0$ to be the zero vector space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the field $F$ in two different roles here: as the set of available scalars on one hand, and as the set of vectors on the other. So strictly speaking, we have two distinguishable sets. However,
$$
\underbrace{1}_{scalar} \; \cdot \; \underbrace{1}_{vector}=\underbrace{1}_{vector}=\underbrace{1}_{vector} \; \cdot \; \underbrace{1}_{scalar}
$$
so keeping the two distinguished would be a nightmare in comparison to simply considering them as one set. But in any case, $F$ is a one-dimensional vector space over $F$ as is $\{0\}$ a zero-dimensional vector space over $F.$

Comment: Sometimes computer code needs/wants to put this distinction in writing, and so "$1$" is a scalar and "$[1]$" is a vector, but this isn't required in math.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Yes. Another - mathematical - example is diagonal, square matrices with only one entry in the diagonal. These build a one-dimensional vector space, but its vectors are usually written as $\lambda \cdot I_n$ where the isomorphism is noted despite the fact that it isn't a necessity. A subtle distinction is on the logical background: We need to require $1\in F$ as a field axiom, but considered as a vector space, $1\in V=F$ is a corollary of $V\neq \{0\}.$